# How can I give browser events to my .wasm program without calling emscripten_sleep?

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I'm currently porting the original DOOM to WebAssembly.  I've got it all "working" but calling `emscripten_sleep` every event loop is prohibitively slow.

The following two lines are inserted into the game loop.  CheckForEvent checks to see if my javascript has put any events into my game.

```
...
        emscripten_sleep(0);
        CheckForEvent();
...

void CheckForEvent() {
    if (event.type) {
        printf("Found event type %d, data1: %d\n", event.type, event.data1);
        event_t * e = malloc(sizeof(event_t));
        e->type = event.type;
        e->data1 = event.data1;
        e->data2 = event.data2;
        e->data3 = event.data3;
        D_PostEvent(e);
        event.type = 0;
        event.data1 = 0;
        event.data2 = 0;
        event.data3 = 0;
        consumed = 1;
    }
}
```

Even using this solution, I still need to call a "sleep" to give javascript a chance to insert them.

Is there any way for WebAssembly to receive browser events without having to halt execution and ask javascript?

Comment: Just an idea, you could try to always keep some ( more than one) calls to `CheckForEvent` into the browsers event loop by using `setTimeout` with a wait time of 0. That way, whenever the stack is empty your checker would run.

Comment: Or maybe semi-recursively call `CheckForEvent` by using the same technique. That's probably easier than maintaining a always emptying pool of watcher subs.

Comment: Is this using Asyncify with the new upstream backend? `emscripten_sleep(0);` etc. should be very fast there, and allow events to arrive. Please file an issue if not!